# Failed: Cannot read property 'saveFullPageScreen' of undefined

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I came across protractor-image-comparison and wanted to test it out.

I made a limited test based on the [example of the website](https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-image-comparison), and I get the error

> Failed: Cannot read property 'saveFullPageScreen' of undefined.

The `browser.imageComparison` is not defined.
It's strange I get this error following the example. There is limited support for protractor so I ask it here.

```
----------------- test.spec.ts --------------
import { browser, } from 'protractor';
import { Urls,  DashboardPage } from '../utils';

fdescribe('protractor-image-comparison desktop', () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await Urls.gotoDashboard();
    await DashboardPage.getVPoints();
  //  await DashboardPage.removeDebugInfo();
  });

it('should save some screenshots', async() => {
  // Save a full page screens
   await  .saveFullPageScreen('fullPage', { /* some options*/ });
   });
it('should compare successful with a baseline', async() => {
   // Check a full page screens
   expect(await browser.imageComparison.checkFullPageScreen('fullPage', { /* some options*/ })).toEqual(0);
   });
});

-------------- part of jasmine.ts ---------------
plugins: [
        {
            // The module name
            package: 'protractor-image-comparison',
            // Some options, see the docs for more
            options: {
                baselineFolder: join(process.cwd(), './baseline/'),
                formatImageName: `{tag}-{logName}-{width}x{height}`,
                screenshotPath: join(process.cwd(), '.tmp/'),
                savePerInstance: true,
                autoSaveBaseline: true,
                blockOutToolBar: true,
                clearRuntimeFolder: true,
                // ... more options
            },
        },
    ],
```

Failures:

> `1) protractor-image-comparison desktop should save some screenshots
>     Message:
>       Failed: Cannot read property 'saveFullPageScreen' of undefined
>     Stack:
>       TypeError: Cannot read property 'saveFullPageScreen' of undefined
>           at Object.<anonymous> (c:\projects\vital10-frontend\e2e\jasmine\image_compair\test.spec.ts:119:83)
>           at step (c:\projects\vital10-frontend\e2e\jasmine\image_compair\test.spec.ts:75:27)
>           at Object.next (c:\projects\vital10-frontend\e2e\jasmine\image_compair\test.spec.ts:24:53)
>           at c:\projects\vital10-frontend\e2e\jasmine\image_compair\test.spec.ts:17:71
>           at new Promise (<anonymous>)
>           at __awaiter (c:\projects\vital10-frontend\e2e\jasmine\image_compair\test.spec.ts:3:12)
>           at UserContext.<anonymous> (c:\projects\vital10-frontend\e2e\jasmine\image_compair\test.spec.ts:110:16)
>           at c:\projects\vital10-frontend\node_modules\jasminewd2\index.js:112:25
>           at new ManagedPromise (c:\projects\vital10-frontend\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:1077:7)
>           at ControlFlow.promise (c:\projects\vital10-frontend\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2505:12)
>       From: Task: Run it("should save some screenshots") in control flow
>           at UserContext.<anonymous> (c:\projects\vital10-frontend\node_modules\jasminewd2\index.js:94:19)
>           at c:\projects\vital10-frontend\node_modules\jasminewd2\index.js:64:48
>           at ControlFlow.emit (c:\projects\vital10-frontend\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\events.js:62:21)
>           at ControlFlow.shutdown_ (c:\projects\vital10-frontend\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2674:10)
>           at c:\projects\vital10-frontend\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2599:53
>       From asynchronous test:
>       Error
>           at Suite.<anonymous> (c:\projects\vital10-frontend\e2e\jasmine\image_compair\test.spec.ts:109:5)
>           at Object.<anonymous> (c:\projects\vital10-frontend\e2e\jasmine\image_compair\test.spec.ts:93:1)
>           at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:868:30)
>           at Module.m._compile (c:\projects\vital10-frontend\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:392:23)
>           at Module.m._compile (c:\projects\vital10-frontend\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:392:23)
>           at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:10)`

Comment: found the issue. its due to a await browser.restart(); in the code

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs you are missing `browser.imageComparison` before `.saveFullPageScreen`

Comment: Yes but should that not be the plugin i Loaded with package: 'protractor-image-comparison', ?